# Capybara's Selenium driver won't click Jquery Mobile buttons

Tags: selenium, jquery-mobile, capybara

Capybara's Selenium driver won't click on JQuery Mobile formatted buttons.  It thinks the button is not visible.

Has anyone seen this issue and got around it?

I created a "greenfield" app demonstrating this issue here:
https://github.com/jevy/JQuery_Mobile_Capybara

```
@javascript
Scenario: Clicking a button doesn't complain # features/click_jq_mobile_button.feature:7
  Given I am on the home page                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
  Given I press "Some Button"                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52
    Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotDisplayedError)
    [remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/atoms.js:9442:in `unknown'
    [remote server] file:///var/folders/fG/fGiEX6gLHQyvWGWb-5MpfU+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110525-21904-h3s00b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:256:in `unknown'
    [remote server] file:///var/folders/fG/fGiEX6gLHQyvWGWb-5MpfU+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110525-21904-h3s00b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:305:in `unknown'
    [remote server] file:///var/folders/fG/fGiEX6gLHQyvWGWb-5MpfU+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110525-21904-h3s00b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:320:in `unknown'
    [remote server] file:///var/folders/fG/fGiEX6gLHQyvWGWb-5MpfU+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110525-21904-h3s00b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:197:in `unknown'
    (eval):2:in `send'
    (eval):2:in `click_button'
    ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:53:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/'
    features/click_jq_mobile_button.feature:9:in `Given I press "Some Button"'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/click_jq_mobile_button.feature:7 # Scenario: Clicking a button doesn't complain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("$('#buttonName').click()");
```

this will work with Selenium 2 and jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara's DOM polling might be finding your selector while the page is loaded and inactive (before the jQueryMobile page transition effect is complete).  I solved this problem by scoping my selector as follows:

```
before do
  click_link "get_ajax_page"
  should have_selector(".ui-page-active #my_id")
  click_link "link_on_ajax_page"
end
```

The `have_selector` will block the script until the page is active.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds familiar but I think we may have solved it by moving off Selenium to capybara-webkit:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/4583605733/capybara-webkit

Comment: After more playing around with it, JQuery Mobile does some funky (neat!) stuff with the DOM.  It intercepts each button click and appends the next page to the DOM of THIS page.  It makes the previous page invisible.  So, in a wizard you may have 5 buttons with the id='next'.  The way to differentiate between active elements on THIS page is to find the elements part of the <div class='ui-current'> element.  I'll have to add a Capybara step for that.